# Getting " Logs eventsource failed with: 400 Bad Request" in Heroku logs

Tags: heroku, jhipster, heroku-cli

I am trying to understand why my JHipster app is not working when i deploy it to Heroku (It does locally) so my first thought was going to the logs. However when i type $ heroku logs i receive back the following error.

> 571 borgesan:~/bitbucket/eureka $ heroku logs -n 200
>    ▸    Logs eventsource failed with: 400 Bad Request

What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

I encounter exactly the same log message when deploying a kotlin app that works locally with 'heroku local web'. The web app is  based on a jetty server running on port 5000 (same port as in the kotlin-getting-started example, but different web server).

In parallel, all requests to server are refused with 503 Service available

- Is there a parameter to set somewhere in the heroku configuration or procfile to declare internal port 5000 (to allow mapping between outside port 80 or 443 to internal port 5000)?
- Is it a problem due to CORS or so ? In other words, shall the application accept specific fields of request header ?
- other thing to take care of ?

Thanks